# Lin Alg: Show that the Google Matrix is stochastic and regular

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-verification

**Intro:**

$M$ is the google matrix and is given by $ M = (1-m)A + mS $

$S$ is a $n\times n$ matrix where all the coefficients are $1/n$, and $m \in \mathbb R: 0 < m < 1$.

Also I know that $A$ is a link matrix so all the entries in $A$ must be between $ 0$ and $1$.

$A$ represents the link matrix to a disjointed web and $S$ represents a jointed web.

**Attempt on solution:**

$A =  \begin{bmatrix}a_{11}  & \dots & a_{1j} \\ \vdots & \dots & \vdots  \\ a_{j1} & \dots & a_{ij}\end{bmatrix} $

$(1-m)A = \begin{bmatrix}(1-m)a_{11}  & \dots & (1-m)a_{1j} \\ \vdots & \dots & \vdots  \\  (1-m)a_{j1} & \dots & (1-m)a_{ij}\end{bmatrix}$

$ S =     \frac{1}{n} \begin{bmatrix}1  & \dots & 1 \\ \vdots & \dots & \vdots  \\ 1 & \dots & 1\end{bmatrix} $

$mS = \begin{bmatrix}m/n  & \dots & m/n \\ \vdots & \dots & \vdots  \\ m/n & \dots & m/n \end{bmatrix} $

$ M = \begin{bmatrix}(1-m)a_{11} + m/n  & \dots & (1-m)a_{1j} + m/n \\ \vdots & \dots & \vdots  \\  (1-m)a_{j1} + m/n & \dots & (1-m)a_{ij} + m/n \end{bmatrix} $

I now that the sum of each column is $1$ so $\sum_j ((1-m)a_{ij} + m/n) = 1  \Rightarrow$  $M$ is stochastic

$M$ is regular if it exists any $ M^{P} $ where all the entries are positive. This is true because whatever values we insert for $m$ and $n$, $M$ will be positive

Also know that the sum of each column in S is 1.Therefore S is also stochastic.

But is every combination of S and M also stochastic?

**Conclusion:**

But I need help some further help with showing that the matrix is stochastic.

Thank you :D

Comment: It is smarter to see that $(1-m)A + mS$ is a convex combination of two stochastic matrices, so it immediate that it is also stochastic. Regularity is easy, since the matrix $S$ has all positive entries, hence...